# jboss. new gc.log after each restart

Tags: jboss, jvm, garbage

I force jboss to write gc log by this parameters: -verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc.log –XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps.
After each jboss restart gc.log file is overrided. How to save all log file?

Comment: Where are you setting these parameters and what OS are you on?

Comment: @Thor84no run.sh -> JAVA_OPTS. Suse linux.

Comment: Well, there might be better ways, but since you're in an sh file you can always just do something like `logNum = $(ls | grep gc.log | wc -l); cp gc.log gc.log.$logNum` which should back up the previous gc.log file to gc.log.1, gc.log.2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

These options can help:

-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation (enable gc log rotation)

-XX:GCLogFileSize=100m (max size of a gc log file)

-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 (number of gc log files to preserve)